# what is the "@" meaning in a asm inline function?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I looking into a inline asm function, and I found a statement can't understand, the code is:

```
    static inline void arch_local_irq_enable(void)
    {
    unsigned long temp;
    asm volatile(
    "   mrs %0, cpsr    @ arch_local_irq_enable\n"
    "   bic %0, %0, #128\n"
    "   msr cpsr_c, %0"
    : "=r" (temp)
    :
    : "memory", "cc");
    }
```

The code is locate at : arch/arm/include/irqflags.h

In the 1st line, does "@ arch_local_irq_enable" means a comment? If so, would you tell me what document will tell the syntax? I searched in some site, but I failed to found that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [GNU Assembler](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dChars.html) documentation on ARM syntax:

> The presence of a `@' anywhere on a line indicates the start of a comment that extends
>   to the end of that line.

Comment: Highly appreciate for your help!